# How to log only failed WCF call requests in .NET application (client-side)?

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a requirement where I need to log only the failed WCF call request messages in my .NET application so that the failed requests can be re-tried later?

Comment: What constitutes a filed request?  Why not simply have the client use the definition for a failed request and store the request for a later retry or immediately retry it?

Comment: One example of a failed request (..according to me) would be a service timeout exception. Can you elaborate on how we can identify and store the failed WCF request? I tried implementing IClientMessageInspector but it does not seem to work for timeouts. Any other suggestions are welcome!